# Spring security 401 Unauthorized on unsecured endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, postman

I'm trying to configure Spring Security on a Spring Boot application as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
    JwtAuthenticationFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    authenticationTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    return authenticationTokenFilter;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

    //@formatter:off
     httpSecurity
      .csrf()
        .disable()
      .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(this.unauthorizedHandler)
        .and()
      .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login", "/singup", "/subscribers").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Custom JWT based security filter 
    httpSecurity            
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);   

    //@formatter:on

}
}
```

My unauthorizedHandler is:

```
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);

@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
}

}
```

Finally, the REST controller for /subscribers is:

```
@RestController
public class SubscriberRestController {

@Autowired
ISubscribersService subscribersService;

@RequestMapping(value = RequestMappingConstants.SUBSCRIBERS, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Number subscriberCount() {

    return subscribersService.subscribersCount();
}

@RequestMapping(value = RequestMappingConstants.SUBSCRIBERS, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String subscriberPost(@RequestBody SubscriberDocument subscriberDocument) {

    return subscribersService.subscribersInsert(subscriberDocument);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test() {

    return "This is a test";
}

}
```

I use postman to test endpoints and when I do a POST to "localhost:8080/subscribers",  I get:

[image: Postman result]

I want to have opened endpoints (/subscribers) without any security control or credentials check, endpoints for singup and login and secured endpoints for authenticated users.

Thanks! :)

Comment: If I do this, it allows me to access /subscribers but also allows me to access secured REST endpoints. @Sobik

Comment: That is what you programmed yourself by overriding the `requiresAuthentication`. It always will now return this. Why are you implementing JWT support yourself? Spring Security already has an extension for that.

Comment: I'm learning Spring security, my knowledge about spring security is poor. How can use Spring Security default JWT support? @M.Deinum

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @dur ! Log can be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105608756/log.txt). I only made bootRun and after, a POST Request to /subscribers.

Comment: @dur Thanks a lot!!!!!!! Now it's working. Spring were not taking configuration because config package was not on `@ComponentScan(basePackages="...")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Boot was not applying the configuration because couldn't find it. On *Application.java* config package was not included with `@ComponentScan` anotation.

Comment: In default Spring application annotation @Configuration should create configuration bean.

Answer (score 3):

After some researching, here is solution:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { PackageConstants.PACKAGE_CONTROLLERS_REST, PackageConstants.PACKAGE_SERVICES,
        PackageConstants.PACKAGE_SERVICES_IMPL, PackageConstants.PACKAGE_MONGO_REPOSITORIES,
        PackageConstants.PACKAGE_MONGO_REPOSITORIES_IMPL, PackageConstants.PACKAGE_UTILS })
public class Application {

    // Clase principal que se ejecuta en el bootrun

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Main line is `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })` it tells not use Spring Boot Security AutoConfiguration configuration. It is not full answer, because now you have to tell Spring user your Spring Security configuration class. Also i advice you to create Initializer class with init Root Config Classes, ApplicationConfiguration using and refuse to use SpringBoot applications. Something like this:

ApplicationConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.trueport.*")
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ....
}
```

ApplicationSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ....
}
```

Initializer:

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ....
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(ctx);
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        ctx.register(ApplicationConfig.class);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet =     servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME,
            dispatcherServlet);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.setAsyncSupported(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @dikkini !! That not works for me, I don't understand where is my error.

Comment: I have `.antMatchers("/login/**", "/signup/**", "/subscribers").anonymous()` and I get 401 Unauthorized on postman response to http://localhost:8080/subscribers @dikkini

Comment: It doesn't work neither. Maybe some auto Spring boot configuration is making it fail?

Comment: Full code can be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105608756/saying-base-server-security.zip). I'm very grateful for your help :)

Comment: There are not only advice to refuse Spring Boot, but and solution for your problem with Spring Boot. I advice to refuse Spring Boot because it adds a lot of code which you don't know and there are always several solutions: 1. Learn Spring Boot and read how it works deeply. 2. Do not use Spring Boot and control spring application by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If your application is simply saving APIs, and you have included dependency for spring security - for any other reason (Mine was to enables headers X-Frame and Content-Security-Policy), then by default Spring includes servlet filter for csrf protection. If you do not disable this, all requests fail with HTTP 401 error.

To disable it, You create a Configuration class extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and annotated with `EnableWebSecurity`

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
   WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

This [article](https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-security) is worthy the read - very detailed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following to your configure method /error is the default fall back when error occurs to the application due to any exception and it is secured by default.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
//disable CRSF
httpSecurity
        //no authentication needed for these context paths
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/error/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/your Urls that dosen't need security/**").permitAll()
```

Also the below code snippet

```
     @Override
       public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception
         {
          webSecurity
          .ignoring()
           // All of Spring Security will ignore the requests
           .antMatchers("/error/**")
          }
```

Now you will not get 401 and get 500 exception with details when an exception occurred for permitAll Urls